# Unable to decrypt a string using AES 256 algorithm when saved to a file

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes, padding

I am tying to use the AES 256 algorithm in CBC mode. The algorithm works fine (both encryption and decryption) in memory, but if I save the encrypted string into a file, the decryption algorithm fails with the following exception:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
```

My Decryption Logic

```
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
    byte[] raw = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedString);
    byte[] stringBytes = cipher.doFinal(raw);
    String decryptedString = new String(stringBytes, "UTF8");
    return decryptedString;
```

Thoughts?

Comment: This is probably some encoding issue. Please include the complete necessary code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Could you supply sample ciphertext too?

Answer (score 1):

If your code works in-memory, then you can test the following chain:

- get encrypted bytes array
- write it into the file
- read it from the file
- compare original encrypted bytes array vs read from the file

Unit-testing forever!